# Carousel Hidden (0 height) after build

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Would love a second look at this basic code to see why my carousel (and also spinner in a different view) is not showing up after a build (testing or production).

EDIT:
What also might help, is that I have to build as SUDO. Could it be a permissions error? I am not able to run the 'sencha' command as non SUDO b/c I get the following error:

```
/Projects/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.2.288/sencha: line 59: 43741 Trace/BPT trap: 5       java $jvmArgs -jar $BASEDIR/sencha.jar "$@" 2> stderr.txt
```

Thanks,
Steve

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Tutorial', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
fullscreen: true,
xtype: 'tutorial',
requries: [
    'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
    'Ext.dataview.List',
    'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
    'Ext.data.Store'
],
defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
},     
config: {
    layout : {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack  : 'center'
    },   
    scrollable: false,  
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Welcome to MyApp'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'carousel',
            flex: 1,
            height: 90,
            layout: 'fit',
            defaults:{
                layout:'fit'
            },
            items:[{
                html: 'asdfasdfasdf',
                cls: 'card',
                height: 60
            },{
                html: '2asdfasdf',
                cls: 'card',
                height: 60
            }]
        },
        {
            height: 60,
            docked: 'bottom',
            xtype: 'container',
            align: 'middle',
            defaults:{
                layout: {
                    align: 'middle',
                    pack: 'center'
                }


            },                
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    centered: true,
                    cls: 'fb_login',
                    height: 47,
                    margin: '',
                    width: 280, 
                    id:'fb_login_button'     
                }
            ]
        }          
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

So after ripping apart my app to its simplest components and settings, I found and answer to both problems.

The BUILD problem was related to another app overriding the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. Unsetting this allowed sencha commands to run normally.

After that, I did an update to SMD and Sencha Touch.

Looks like my big problem is that Sencha's tolerances during the build process doesn't allow for my confused layout definitions. So moving 'fullscreen:true' to the config block, removing 'scrollable:false', and not mixing fit and height seemed to eliminate the bugginess.

I do wish that the build debugger was a bit more robust to identify where the app was breaking. I didn't get any console errors when running the compiled app in any of my browsers.